# Solve a system of trigonometric equations

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

How can I solve this system of trigonometric equations analytically? It is from physics class.
$$
\begin{cases}
30t\cos{\alpha}=50\\
-30t\sin{\alpha}-4.9t^2=0
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Hint: try moving the $t^2$ term to the other side, squaring the two equations, and adding them together. What happens to the trigonometric terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Squaring both the equations, you will get $900t^2\cos^2{\alpha}=2500\\
900t^2\sin^2{\alpha}={4.9}^2t^4$.

Note that  $\sin^2{\alpha}+\cos^2{\alpha}=1$.

So add both the equations and solve for $t$ using the substitution  $t^2=u$.

Comment: Turn it into a quadratic is the gist of my answer but this is much nicer+faster.

Comment: @Mason Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$30t\cos{\alpha}=50 \implies t=\frac{5}{3} \sec\alpha$

You can plug this information into the other equation and solve:

$$-30t\sin{\alpha}-4.9t^2=0\implies -30(\frac{5}{3} \sec\alpha)\sin{\alpha}-4.9(\frac{5}{3} \sec\alpha)^2=0$$

$$-50(\tan\alpha)-4.9(\frac{5}{3} \sec\alpha)^2=0$$

$$-50(\tan\alpha)-4.9\frac{25}{9} \sec^2\alpha=0$$

$$-50(\tan\alpha)-4.9\frac{25}{9} (\tan^2\alpha+1)=0$$

Taking $y=\tan\alpha$ you can solve a quadratic equation.
$$-50(y)-4.9\frac{25}{9} (y^2+1)=0$$

I think you're probably in good shape from here?

Comment: This results in negative alpha but its a real physics problem, so it must be positive.

Comment: The angle cannot be negative? Add $2\pi$?

Comment: Adding 2π gives angles greater than 90°

Comment: @Stepii Which also doesn't make sense in the context of the problem?

Comment: What did you get for $y$. Maybe I made an error... [Here's y](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-50y-4.9*25%2F9(y%5E2%2B1)%3D0)

Comment: But I don't know the physics element of this so I am not sure why a negative angle doesn't make sense in the context. I can see the gravity in the $-4.9$ but otherwise I am not sure what we are doing? Why can't it be negative? 

Also, if you solve the problem the way Thomas Shelby suggests for $t$. You can plug it in and find $\alpha$. Does this also result in a negative value?

Comment: @Manson with Thomas Shelby's method I get 4 solutions, two positives and two negatives. With yours I only get 2 negative solutions.

Comment: That's because on step 1 with Thomas Shelby's answer we square both sides. That will add in the extraneous solutions. $x=-1$ has only one solution but $x^2=(-1)^2$ has two solutions.

Comment: @Manson maybe I made an error in the physic statement of the problem. But I was searching for positive solutions (time cannot be negative).

Comment: Actually [they](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=30tcos(a)%3D50,+-30tsin(a)-4.9t%5E2%3D0) are not extraneous solutions.

Comment: My answer results in negative angles not negative times.

Comment: @Manson with negative angles the time also is negative. You can see it in the link.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pp1zjytefg

Comment: @Manson maybe there is an error somewhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86337/discussion-between-mason-and-stepii).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. This is not an answer. Just part of a chat conversation that we are not really suppose to be having via comments.

[image]

This is the image from the link you shared. Unless I am reading this graph wrong it says: That when $a<0$ then $t>0$

Comment: The extraneous solutions are when $a>0$ because it implies that $t<0$ which as you have commented makes little sense often in physics problems.

Comment: But that solutions (with the angle and time both positive) satisfy the given system